# POP3 Gmail account to SMTP

Tags: email, imap, pop3

Not sure if this is the right way to ask but ..

A while ago I added a account to my Gmail using the POP3 settings of my hoster. Now, all e-mails are in Gmail, and not on the original server anymore.

Is there anyway to redo this? So get all  mail, from the POP3 account, back to the original server. So I can connect with IMAP again?

Hope someone can help, not sure if this is the right place though. If not, let me know and I'll look for the answer somewhere else.

Comment: Does your original host support IMAP?  If so, you can use a full featured email client like Thunderbird, and add both accounts, and just drag all the messages from one to the other.

Comment: It does, thanks I'll try it now